# How to make an animation using PyPlot.jl with multiple axes?

Tags: matplotlib, animation, julia, julia-plots

I would like to create an animation of two axes. In the simple example illustrated below, I would like to plot two matrices using `imshow` as a function of time.

Coming from python, I would create an animation using `matplotlib.animation` similar to this:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.animation as anim
using PyPlot
import IJulia

A = randn(20,20,20,2)

fig, axes = PyPlot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 2.5))
ax1, ax2 = axes

function make_frame(i)
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.imshow(A[:,:,i+1, 1])
    ax2.imshow(A[:,:,i+1, 2])
end

withfig(fig) do
    myanim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, make_frame, frames=size(A,3), interval=20, blit=false)
    myanim[:save]("test.mp4", bitrate=-1, extra_args=["-vcodec", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p"])
end
```

This however just creates a blank animation.
Do I need to use an `init_func` in the FuncAnimation? Do I need to enable blitting? Or can I update the artist using a `set_data` attribute?

Comment: Works fine for me - how are you viewing the output?

Comment: What platform are you running? Did you link an external python library to PyCall or an internal via Conda.jl ? Executing the above code as a file with julia (1.8.2) gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: I can get it to run and give the proper image if I run without the withfig(fig) surround (Julia 1.8.2, internal Python). With the withfig surround I get the segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `IJulia` for this routine. If you plan to include the routine in a notebook, just run the code and then view the file you create, without using `withfig`. `withfig` is causing your animation creation to abort for some reason, probably because it expects something within an IJulia environment to be set differently.

This works:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.animation as anim
using PyPlot

A = randn(20,20,20,2)
fig, axes = PyPlot.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(7, 2.5))
ax1, ax2 = axes

function make_frame(i)
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax1.imshow(A[:,:,i+1, 1])
    ax2.imshow(A[:,:,i+1, 2])
end

myanim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, make_frame, frames=size(A,3), interval=20, blit=false)
myanim[:save]("test.mp4", bitrate=-1, extra_args=["-vcodec", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p"])
# now you can call your video viewer on "test.mp4"
```

Comment: I can confirm that it actually works without using `withfig`. What is the deal with `withfig` then in the first place? Thanks for your answer. I think this solves it then.

Comment: `withfig` is for using matplotlib in an IPython notebook when the plot is to be interactive, like a widget. Perhaps unless it is used specifically in such a context something in a relevant ipython DLL may throw an error?